# read application logs from logs folder after hosted using docker in linux

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, serilog

We have hosted .net core api in linux server using docker. so issue is reading application logs from Logs folder which we are not getting in container. our docker code is :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 50147

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Services.csproj", "Services/"]
COPY ["Portal.Common/Portal.Common.csproj", "Portal.Common/"]
COPY ["Portal.Domains/Portal.Domains.csproj", "Portal.Domains/"]
COPY ["Portal.Business/Portal.Business.csproj", "Portal.Business/"]
COPY ["Portal.DataAccess/Portal.DataAccess.csproj", "Portal.DataAccess/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PortalServices/PortalServices.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PortalServices"
RUN dotnet build "PortalServices.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PortalServices.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PortalServices.dll"]
```

so inside app path only dll files are there. So how can we read logs from folder???

We implemented serilog to solution and saving to solutionpath/Logs/log.txt 
In local it is storing in this path.

Please help!!

Comment: You can use docker logs <containerid> right?

Comment: Have you taken a look into the docker container once it is up and running? (by [attaching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) to it and checking the directory where you are outputting the logs? Also, what is the directory where you are outputting the logs? You could also use [volume mounting ](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to use a directory on your local machine for the logs directory.

Comment: @illug i have tried that, not showing anything....and i think it will show container run time logs..but i need logs from folder

Comment: @Jamie Taylor  yes , container  is running fine, after attaching to it in /app folder only dll files are there, also checked other path but did not get anything..

Comment: What / how logs are your putting out?

Comment: @illug We are using serilog, and saving in Logs/log.txt path.

Comment: @S.Mishra if you run the code locally (i.e. not within docker), are the logs present where you would expect them?

Comment: @S.Mishra can you post the config for serilog? I use that as well without any problems and docker logs will show the logs. This is my log config:

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build())
                .WriteTo.Console(new CompactJsonFormatter())
                .CreateLogger();

            host.UseSerilog(logger);

Answer (score 0):

Change folder permission to 777 where you want to store logs.

> chmod 777 .
>
> docker run -d -t -i -p 80:80 -v /usr/Logs:/app/Logs --name
> testContainer testImage